# My test case is failing for spyon in angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a component which removes clients using endpoint in service and I am trying to make test case for coverage and it's failing:

Ts file:

```
 removeClients(): void { 
    if (this.accountId && this.clientList) {
      this.programMgrService.removeClients(this.accountId, this.clientList)
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log('Client remooved successfully.');
          this.dialogRef.close();
          window.location.reload();
        },
        bad => {
          console.log("Error occurred.." + bad);
        });
    }
    else {
      this.loggerSvc.log('Missing accountId or Client List');
    }
  }
```

spec.ts file:

```
it('test removeClients()', async() =>{  
    component.accountId = 4521;
    component.clientList = [4529, 4564, 6588];
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    spyOn(programMgrService, 'removeClients');
    expect(component.removeClients()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    component.removeClients();
  });

  it('test removeClients() throw error', async() =>{
    let err = new Error('error');
    spyOn(programMgrService, 'removeClients').and.returnValue(throwError(err));   
    component.removeClients();
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I know doing something wrong to make test case so it will be great help if someone helps me with this test case.

Answer (score 0):

Your first test is expecting for `removeClients` to be called without making the actual call first... the order is wrong, try the following:

```js
it('test removeClients()', () => {  
    component.accountId = 4521;
    component.clientList = [4529, 4564, 6588];

    spyOn(console, 'log');
    spyOn(programMgrService, 'removeClients');

    component.removeClients(); // you make the actual call
    
    expect(component.removeClients()).toHaveBeenCalled(); // you expect the function to be called
})
```

For the second test, testing `true` to be truthy doesn't make sense, I'm not sure I've seen/used a `bad` callback for `subscribe`, based on the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observer), you have, `next`, `error` and `complete`. For the test, try the following:

```js
it('test removeClients() throw error', async() =>{
    let err = new Error('error');
    spyOn(programMgrService, 'removeClients').and.returnValue(throwError(err));   
    spyOn(console, 'log');

    component.removeClients();

    expect(programMgrService.removeClients).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error occurred..' + err');
  })
```